# Does a no-touch policy really work?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, airline-operations

In Boeing 787 and Airbus 350 aircrafts, more than half of the aircraft body is made of composite material. The composite structure of the fuselage does not indicate the damage when the body is contacted and damaged by the ground support equipment. That's why an airline company I’m familiar with issued a statement for the entire fleet to the ground staff indicating "do not touch the aircraft while servicing" (a no-touch policy).

How can the passenger mobile stairs be aligned safely from the ground without contacting such high aircraft passenger doors?  Wouldn't it be possible for passengers to fall down from the gap between the aircraft and the mobile stairs, especially in windy weather?
What else can be done not to damage composite structured aircraft fuselage?

Comment: Where is this airline?  Asia somewhere?  My spidey sense tells me this is China or similar.

Comment: @Sean, « The composite structure of the fuselage does not indicate the damage when the body is contacted and damaged by the ground support equipment », please could you justify this assumption ?

Comment: Kindly see those videos for justification on youtube: https://youtu.be/TJofm5MuLoc                                                  https://youtu.be/Ce6fE_eT_vE

Comment: @GolfCharlie, very interesting, thank you

Comment: @GolfCharlie, so if I understand properly, the parts that do touch the aircraft even though made of material that do not damage the surface of the airframe, might internally cause deep damages.

Comment: @user40476 there is a risk that gse, even though unintentionally harshly contacting the aircraft, may damage the internal structure of the aircraft even if it is not visible from the outside. In the event of such contact, it is essential that the area in which the internal structure is checked using special equipment by authorized persons.

Comment: @user40476: Don't ask me - I'm just the one who fixed GolfCharlie's punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Jet bridges are operated just next to the point at which passengers will enter the aircraft. They have proximity sensors that tell the operator if they getting too close. And the bridge doesn't have to physically touch the aircraft as long as the gap on the walkway is small enough to not pose a danger to the passengers, it just needs to get close enough so that the end of the bridge can extend like an awning and cover the entrance. The parts that do touch the aircraft are usually made of material that will not damage the surface of the airframe.